# Webview: Fatal signal 11 when tapping at bottom nav bar

Tags: webview, crash, android-jetpack-compose, fatal-error

I have a composable where a WebView is embedded an I am not using the Webview in my activity code at all, all it does is sits in composable and being visible.

Now I have a bottom nav bar where I have 4 tabs let say A, B, C, D. I have a WebView which is used to open urls. And that sits in A tab but when in Tab A I clicked tab D and again Tab A, the app crashes with

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 23934 (RenderThread), pid 23898 (.mobile.android)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0000000000000020
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000002  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000000000000001
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000000000000001  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000001  x7  0000000000000001
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x8  aeeabf0bf3658480  x9  aeeabf0bf3658480  x10 00000076cb15c000  x11 000000000000006d
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000004  x13 0000000000000001  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000000000000000
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000000000000001  x17 0000007a4dbb2ec0  x18 00000076ca0be000  x19 0000000000000000
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000000  x21 00000076cb151740  x22 0000000000000000  x23 0000000000000000
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000000000000000  x27 00000077ce2ffb90
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000000  x29 00000076cb151630
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000007a5bd18300  sp  00000076cb151630  pc  0000007a5be95b90  pst 0000000060000000
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000695b90  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkSurface::getCanvas()+16) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000005182fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::GLFunctorDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+860) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 00000000005a5634  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+116) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00000000008d6bd4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (skgpu::v1::Device::drawDrawable(SkCanvas*, SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*)+344) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00000000004f7d70  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::$_37::__invoke(void const*, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+136) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000004f4f54  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DisplayListData::draw(SkCanvas*) const+128) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00000000004de5b8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1748) (BuildId: 5e7ceec4d8844b047ab06d2f7ae9c6c5)
    12-08 19:29:21.885 22765 22765 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000004dece4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)
```

Weview Code

```
   @Composable
private fun TestWebView(url: String, onReceivedError: (WebResourceError) -> Unit) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
     var mWebView: WebView? = null
   // var webView: WebView? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

    // State to track whether the WebView is loading or not
    var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .verticalScroll(scrollState),
            factory = { context ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                    mWebView = WebView(context);
                    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                        override fun onReceivedError(
                            view: WebView?,
                            request: WebResourceRequest?,
                            error: WebResourceError?
                        ) {
                            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                            error?.let { onReceivedError(it) }
                            isLoading = false
                        }

                        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                            view: WebView?,
                            request: WebResourceRequest?
                        ): Boolean {
                            view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
                            return true
                        }

                        override fun onRenderProcessGone(
                            view: WebView?,
                            detail: RenderProcessGoneDetail?
                        ): Boolean {
                            return false
                        }

                        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                            isLoading = true
                        }

                        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                            isLoading = false
                        }
                    }
                    settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
                    this.alpha = 0.99F
                    loadUrl(url)
                }
            },
            update = { webView ->
                webView.loadUrl(url)
            }
        )

        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }

// Dispose the WebView to avoid memory leaks when the composable is removed
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            onDispose {
                mWebView?.clearCache(true);
                mWebView?.clearHistory();
                mWebView?.onPause();
                mWebView?.removeAllViews();
                mWebView?.destroy();
                mWebView = null
            }
        }
    }
}
```